# Troubleshooting custom printer installer (Ends in error)

Tags: macos, network-printer, installation-package

I've been working on making a payload-ed Package that installs the PPD files for specific printers in our deployment and then adds the appropriate ones to CUPS and registers them for use.  To do this, I'm using Packages 1.2.5 on the Catalina Public Beta 1.  The package successfully builds and installs on a target machine (Mojave 10.14.4), however despite running my post-install script and adding the (working!) printer to CUPS, the installer ends in an error.

This is my first time working with Packages and with custom payload packages in general so I'm new to the whole pre-install/post-install script business.  I'm trying to be a good Mac Admin, hence why I care about cleaning up the installer so it says that it finishes nicely with a big green checkmark.  (The package will eventually be deployed via MDM, so I assume that this may cause problems with that).

For reference, the payload includes a bunch of files that are put into /Library/Printers/ and /Library/Printers/PPDs/Contents/Resources/ and here's a copy of the extremely complex post-install script:

```
#!/bin/bash

cp "/Library/Printers/PPDs/Contents/Resources/RICOH MP C6004" /etc/cups/ppd/Admin_Copier.ppd
lpadmin -p "Admin_Copier" -v "lpd://###.###.###.###/" -P "/etc/cups/ppd/Admin_Copier.ppd" -o printer-is-shared=false -E -D "Admin Copier" -L "Mail Room"
cupsenable "Admin_Copier"
cupsaccept "Admin_Copier"

return 0
```

Any help is appreciated!